# How to export Photoshop file to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers, eps

I have created a graphics in **Photoshop CS6** and I saves it in **`.eps`** file format, and when I opened it in the **Illustrator CC** it is not recognizing any element more over if I zoom in the graphics is become blur. One more issue that when I open .eps file in Illustrator I found all my Photoshop layered are merged together.

I know Photoshop generate Raster image where as Illustrator generate Vector image, but `Encapsulated PostScript files (.eps)` is supported by both the tools so it should work?

So I want to know how to create/save a graphics in Photoshop and open it in Illustrator to do any other editing or changes.

Please Note: I'm just a beginner in this 2 tools.

Comment: EPS is not automatically a vector format. Just save as .psd and open that with Illustrator.

Comment: @wch1zpink has given you great instructions for ensuring that your layers are available in Illustrator, but I just want to point out that s/he is doing exactly what scott suggested; opening the native PSD file. There are very few situations that I run into where it isn't better to keep your original file in its native format when wanting to share it between photoshop and Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a Photoshop document, the initial image resolution is it important.  Create the new document at 300 ppi image resolution.  This will help the image from appearing blurry or pixelated when you zoom in.

[image]

When saving your new Photoshop document, be sure to enable the "Layers" option in the save dialog box. Save this file as a Photoshop .PSD document

[image]

In illustrator, go to menu item File/Open and choose your Photoshop document and enable the convert layers to objects option and the import  hidden layers option if you want all objects from Photoshop visible in illustrator layers panel

[image]

Now your Photoshop document will be opened in illustrator, containing all of the layers from your Photoshop document

[image]

Comment: thanks, for such an explained answer, let me try it first.